# Checkboxes binding to two objects with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm creating a checkbox list. The list is created from this object:

```
this.definedRoles = ko.observableArray([]);
```

But another object has which boxes should be checked.

```
this.userToAdd = {
        ID: ko.observable(""),
        FirstName: ko.observable(""),
        LastName: ko.observable(""),
        Active: ko.observable(""),
        Email: ko.observable(""),
        Roles: ko.observableArray([])//these are the values of the checkboxes
    };
```

I'm able to generate the checkboxes using:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root.definedRoles" style="list-style:none;">
     <li>
         <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Id" value="" />
              <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
         </label>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Every time I try to add a binding to check certain boxes using

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Id, checked: $root.userToAdd.Roles.Active" value="" />
```

It yields no results. Not sure how to apply this binding. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a function that checks whether the given user has the role or not, like so:

```
var User = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable(""),
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(""),
    self.LastName = ko.observable(""),
    self.Active = ko.observable(""),
    self.Email = ko.observable(""),
    self.Roles = ko.observableArray([])//these are the values of the checkboxes,

    self.IsRoleActive = function(role) {
        for(i=0; i<self.Roles().length; i++) { 
            if(self.Roles()[i] == role && self.Roles()[i].Active) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

var userToAdd = new User();
```

And then your binding should look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="value: Id, checked: $root.userToAdd.IsRoleActive"/>
```

Of course, this all works only if `Roles` and `definedRoles`are both arrays of strings.

Answer (score 0):

As Roles is an observable, you're not calling it correctly:

```
$root.userToAdd.Roles().Active
```

Though as it is an array, then `.Active` isn't going to resolve to anything, I'd have thought.

Is it just an array of strings detailing the roles the user is in? If it is, then you need to do something along the lines of:

```
$root.userToAdd.Roles.indexOf(Name()) !== -1
```

to see if the array contains the string of the role.